# Replace HTML button by HTML input tag using java script or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **HTML button** in first column of all rows in table with unique id. I want to replace button of particular id by **input tag** from success of ajax.

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="1" type="button">Verify</button>
</td>
```

From ajax success I want to replace button in td of id 1 by below

```
<input type='text' name='someName' value='some value from ajax response'>
```

I tried using **replace** but not working

```
var html = '<input type="text" name="someName" value="some value from ajax response">';

var parent = document.getElementById(1).parentNode;

parent.innerHTML=parent.replaceChild(html,parent.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: Funny that's it's simpler to create new question, format it, than google one phrase "jquery replace element by id". http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: @dfsq then mark the question as a duplicate. We do want answers to be here on SO instead of having to search through Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is set the HTML

```js
var html = '<input type="text" name="someName" value="some value from ajax response">';
var parent = document.getElementById('1').parentNode;
parent.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<table>
  <td>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="1" type="button">Verify</button>
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this example, you can use `parent.innerHTML = html`

`replaceChild` takes a node, not an html string. So to stay closer to your original idea, you can do

```
 node = document.createElement("input");
 node.id = ...; // set other properties
 parent.replaceChild(node, parent.firstElementChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.fn.replaceWith()`

```js
var html = '<input type="text" name="someName" value="some value from ajax response">';

$("#1").replaceWith(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="1" type="button">Verify</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the conditional statement to solve this.

```
(Your Condition) ? <button class="btn btn-success" id="1" type="button">Verify</button> : <input type='text' name='someName' value='some value from ajax response'>
```